# Problem with Unity 2019.429f1, why scene does not appear?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem in Unity 2019.429f1. No scene opens when Iopen a project. I also can't add a new one or even open SampleScene (nothing happens when I click). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwGwJ.png)

Comment: Do you already have one of those two types of windows open? Hit `control+tab` when in unity. If you do not have a windows already open when attempting to cycle through Unitys popped out windows, reset your editor layout. Click the layout button on the top right of Unity, then select one of the preset options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so there's a clear answer to the question I'll expand my comment a bit. In the screenshot the project window is taking up the entirety of Unitys application space. It could be that the Game and Editor windows were mistakenly dragged off and made standalone windows. Whenever in any application on Windows, I believe hitting `control+tilde` should cycle through all windows of a particular process (Control+tab cycles through all open applications - made a mistake in the comment).

If there's no luck here, Unity allows a complete reset to the current layout of the editor. On the top right of the Unity application window, there is a drop down titled `Layout`. Clicking this drop down shows a number of presets. Click any one of these to get the editor window to return to a more normal state.